# Average for weekly and monthly on Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that breaks down a daily log we fill out.
When filled out each day, the report tab uses a series of formulas to display averages as well as hard counts.

One thing i need help with is my weekly and monthly averages. I am unable to break that information down the way i want.
In rows 3 and 4, i'd like to display the averages for each name on a weekly and monthly basis. I used columns V and W to show the weekly and monthly numbers, which have helped me with other parts of the data table.
[image]
Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Would love to know why my post was down voted.

Comment: You'll need another range where you can list down your monthnums (1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) down in their own rows (assuming A1:A12 on another sheet) then do a `=SUMIF($A$1, Report!$W:$W, C:C)` to get the totals for Mike. Copy that down for all 12 months and across for all of your people. Then you can do your average off of that. Rinse and Repeat for Weeknum.

Comment: Also, don't sweat the downvotes. Everyone has their reason, and if they didn't bother typing it out here and there is only one of them, then just disregard. You may find a bit more help here if you were to share more than just 3 dates and your expected results for what a "Monthly average" would be. It may make perfect sense to you, but without a definition or some expected results it may lead to confusion.

Comment: That makes complete sense. This is a rather new spreadsheet thats been rebuilt and reused for multiple tracking reasons. I have 3 years of data on another version, but we don't really care for weekly and monthly averages on the other sheets. This was just a request from the guy who's filling it out. And thank you for the clearing up the downvote thing for me. After so many questions i've asked and all end up with downvotes, it gets a little irritating. Thank you JNevill